# MySql - left join with where on related table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have this tables :

```
users
id|name
1|luke
2|john
3|paul

verifications
id|user_id|points|deleted_at
1|1|10|null
2|2|20|null
3|3|30|1-1-2017
```

The goal is to get all users sorted by verification.points but consider verification points if verification is not soft deleted, otherwise use null for verification points. 
With this query :

```
select users.name from users 
    left join verifications on verifications.user_id = users.id
    where verifications.deleted_at is null
    ORDER BY  verifications.id
```

I get this results :

```
luke (10 ponts)
john (20 points)
```

But i want

```
paul (null points because left join)
luke (10 ponts)
john (20 ponts)
```

30 points in paul verifications should not be considered because verification is soft deleted, we should use null for his verification points in order by.

any ideas ?

PS : please I want a solution without subqueries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do away with the `where` and check `deleted_at` in the join condition.

```
select u.name, v.points from users u
left join verifications v on v.user_id = u.id and v.deleted_at is null
ORDER BY  v.points
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `where` condition and use a `case` expression to show `null` points if `deleted_at` has a value.

```
select u.name,case when v.deleted_at is null then v.points end as points
from users u
left join verifications on v.user_id = u.id
```